# Cassandra - dstat

Tags: linux, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm new to dstat and I'm currently using it to analyze the performance of Cassandra writes whilst an ingest is taking place.

Could someone please explain how I could read the outputs provided and the units used?

I have run dstat lrvn 10 to produce the image below.

For instance, what is the unit of io/total here. Is this a percentage or number of read/writes every 10 sec? Do the colours resemble anything?

[image: dstat lrvn 10]

Thanks
Majd

Comment: Which plugin are you using for io stats?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I am not a dstat expert, but http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/dstat/ may have some more detailed info. Hope this helps.

Sven

Answer (score 0):

io/total are the number of IOPs.

You can find this information documented in the plugin that you are using.